# Gson Deserialization json which contains parameter that can be string or object

Tags: java, json, string, gson, deserialization

I have a Json like below.

```
{
    "myItemArray": [
        {
            "id": "c8c1", 
            "price": 18, 
            "display": {
                "inneritemName1": "innerItemValue1", 
                "inneritemName2": "innerItemValue2",
                "inneritemName3": "innerItemValue3"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id": "cac1", 
            "price": 2, 
            "display": "Lemonate"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see that the item in my array has a parameter called "display" which can be String or Object. How can I deserialize this json using Gson?

I don't want to deserialize this string manually is there any other way to to this?

Comment: What structure do you intend to deserialize this into?  Display needs a type, so are you just going to have it as a generic object type or do something to massage the data into a like type?  Put another way, what do you want display to end up as?

Comment: you probably need a custom deserializer for that field

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson, but have to build a class, get each Json attribute  into the relevent attribute in the Java class.

I highly recomand [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/) library, you only need to setup the Java class, and it takes care of the mapping and parsing.

Comment: how do you suggest handling the specific issue the OP is describing?

Comment: checked this, for this kind of mapping he has to create his own deserializer and orange the proper behiever from class on how to differ between them.
this is an example on how to do this with Jackson http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization